# Building table data from multi-layered object

Tags: javascript

I am using material-ui table to display some data from an object called arrCollection. You can see the structure below from my console log output of arrCollection.

[image: Console log ouput of arrCollection]

The table data needs this format:

```js
data = {[
    {white: "David", black: "Michael", speed: "classical"},
    {white: "Sue", black: "Collette", speed: "classical"},
    {white: "Jon", black: "Steve", speed: "rapid"},
]}
```

I've been looking at this code to get me started:

```js
for (const property in importedRecords) {
    console.log(importedRecords[property].moves);
}
```

This lets me output moves, but I am a bit lost on how to get my data into the format required as shown in my data example.

How would I go about this the correct way?

Edit: I am looping through the records now to build the object ready for the table. This is my current best effort, but fails if a property does not exist, with a "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error.

```
const parseTableData = arrCollection => {
    let importedRecords = arrCollection;
    let parsedData = {};
    for (const property in importedRecords) {
      parsedData.white = importedRecords[property].players.white.user.name;
      parsedData.black = importedRecords[property].players.black.user.name;
      parsedData.whiteRating = importedRecords[property].white.rating;
      parsedData.blackRating = importedRecords[property].black.rating;
      // console.log(importedRecords[property].moves);
    }
    console.log(parsedData);
  };
```

Comment: Can you put a the data that you wanted to convert? It's hard to replicate if you're using a picture

Comment: Also, the table that you've shown is in an invalid format. Perhaps you only wanted the result to be array? not an object?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw I can't see any table...

Comment: @biberman *The table data needs this format* under this

Comment: For me this is an array of objects which is wrapped in an outer object (in a wrong way)...

Comment: Are the keys static? If so can't you just loop over your data and add the values you want by their path?

Comment: @biberman The structure required for the material-table is shown here: https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started

Comment: @JarneKompier I do indeed want to just loop over my data, but I am a bit new at looping through objects and building another object from it, so seeking some help to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation Jon provided I think I see what your problem is.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}>
        <MaterialTable
          columns={[
            { title: 'Adı', field: 'name' },
            { title: 'Soyadı', field: 'surname' },
            { title: 'Doğum Yılı', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
            { title: 'Doğum Yeri', field: 'birthCity', lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' } }
          ]}
          data={[{ name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }]}
          title="Demo Title"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here you see `data={[{ name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }]}`

This doesn't mean the object your trying to create has to look like this `{[{},{},{}]}` but rather like this `[{},{},{}]` this is without the surrounding `{}`.

The reason it looks like `data={[{},{}]}` is because when you want to pass JavaScript with you jsx it has to be surrounded by `{}` for it to render.

If you make a loop that creates an array of objects and call that array `dataArray` for example you can then put `dataArray` into the data part. Something like this;

```
class App extends Component {
  let dataArray = [
      {white: "David", black: "Michael", speed: "classical"},
      {white: "Sue", black: "Collette", speed: "classical"},
      {white: "Jon", black: "Steve", speed: "rapid"},
  ]
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}>
        <MaterialTable
          columns={[{title: "White", field: "white"},
                    {title: "Black", field: "black"},
                    {title: "Speed", field: "speed"}]}
          data={dataArray}
          title="Demo Title"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I think that should work. How you go about making the `dataArray` is a different issue. But the format should be like that I think.

Try this.

```
const importedRecords = [
    {
        speed: "classical", 
        players: {
            white: {
                user: {name : "a"}}, 
            black: {}
    }},
    {
        speed: "classical", 
        players: {
            white: {
                user: {name : "a"}}, 
            black: {
                user: {name : "b"}}
    }},]

let dataArray = [];

for(const prop in importedRecords)
{
    console.log(simplifiedArrCollection[prop])
    let obj = {};
    try{
        obj.white = simplifiedArrCollection[prop].players.white.user.name;
    }
    catch(exception){
        obj.white = "";
        console.warn(exception)
    }

    try{
        obj.black = simplifiedArrCollection[prop].players.black.user.name;
    }
    catch(exception){
        obj.black = "";
        console.warn(exception)
    }

    try{
        obj.speed = simplifiedArrCollection[prop].speed;
    }
    catch(exception){
        obj.speed = "";
        console.warn(exception)
    }
    
    dataArray.push(obj)
}

console.log(dataArray)
```

I'd recommend using try catch so you can atleast send a warning when the data was missing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although my question is not about how to display it but how to build the table data in the correct format. So in other words, I am looking for a loop code that would parse the data correctly.

Comment: @Jon try this out hope it helps

Comment: That helped thank you. I now see how to structure it. I am trying my loop using your referencing but with the for in loop method. When it comes across a black.user.name where there is no such defined username, the cde breaks, saying the property 'name' is undefined. How should I deal with that?

Comment: Well it kind of depends what you are passing in at the moment. Are you passing in the array you received from you backend / some api. or are you looping through that one and passing each object into the for in loop?

Comment: I've just edited my original post to show the code I am using to loop through the data. The data came from an api call and stored in arrCollection.

Comment: the property black.user.name was a bit of a guess on my part. I dont know how your data looks exactly so I just assumed. you'll have to play around with the code a bit to get the data you are looking for since I dont know what it looks like

Comment: You were correct in the reference, but the data that comes across from the api sometimes has black.user.name, but sometimes it doesn't. Do I need to have lots of if statements that say if (black.user.name exists), then take the name, otherwise, skip?

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I see what you did there and I will run with that. Now in the future I know what to do. Kind regards.